# CURL extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work! php-5.3.13 and WAMP

Tags: php, wampserver

I am trying to install Opencart here I have get a warning that is CURL extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!I have already download php_curl. and also replace it bin\php\php5.3.13\ext in here.

[image]

Here in php extensions php_curl already on.
But in install form showing me crul is off

[image]

I have already restarted my wamp and also restarted install.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you need to enable curl, in php.ini uncomment ;extension=php_curl.dll remove the semi colon at beginning and restart wampp php.ini can be found in wampp/php/php.ini

Comment: Nothing happen,same output.

Comment: make sure you have php_curl.dll in your wampp/php/ext folder (edit) i see you mentioned its there, should work now. have you restarted server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced same problem! You can solve it by 2 ways:

Go to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.x.x\php.ini` 
 change the line from,

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

to:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Than restart your WAMP, I think that will work.

If this does not work for you, try to change your PHP version you can use php-5.4.

Comment: ```;``` means commented out, means inactive line of code, remove ```;``` and it will make this line readable in configuration setting and will load this extension.

Comment: Correct answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For WAMP 2.4 you must uncomment two php.ini files at these locations

```
wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini

wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to WAMP\bin\php(your version of php)\
3. edit php.ini
4. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
5. Navigate to WAMP\bin\Apache(your version of apache)\bin\
6. edit php.ini
7. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
8. Save both
9. Restart WAMP

Answer (score -1):

just try to go to `php/php_extensions/` There will be `php_curl`, if it is **not ticked** pls make it **ticked**.then you can try to proceed.Hope it solves your problem.